# InnoDB MySQL account usage history

Tags: mysql, innodb, logins, log

I would like to view the account usage history. I know it can be viewed
via `my.cnf` through the general query log. But it will slow down the usage of the
DB significantly.

Is there a way to mitigate this or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to log.

One solution (taken from [here](http://mysqlhints.blogspot.ch/2011/01/how-to-log-user-connections-in-mysql.html)) that does not use the general query log is the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE admin;

CREATE TABLE admin.connections (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, connect_time DATETIME NOT NULL, user_host VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, connection_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL);

SET GLOBAL init_connect = "INSERT INTO admin.connections (connect_time, user, connection_id) VALUES (NOW(), CURRENT_USER(), CONNECTION_ID());";
```

This solution uses [the `init_connect` MySQL variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) which stores SQL queries executed each time a user logs in. Now each time a user logs in, it will be logged into the table `admin.connections`. Be sure to check the permissions of all of your users to ensure that they can insert a record into the table.

Another solution, available only for MySQL Enterprise and that I include here for completeness' sake, is to install the [MySQL Enterprise Audit plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/audit-log-installation.html).